# Open a file and write contents to a DIV, span, label, some kind of container

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

I’d like to be able to open a text/html file and write its contents to a container, either an HTML div or an asp label would be fine. 
How do I go about doing this in the C# codefile for the page in question?

Comment: I think there was a question almost identical to this one 3-4 days earlier... Trying to find it, but no luck yet. Anyone?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just want to stream in the file and place the text into the Label.text field:

```
lable1.text= System.IO.File.ReadAllText( path );
```

Comment: Great answer +1, but with a label, it's InnerText or InnerHtml.

Comment: Yes: the .Text property will escape things like < for you.  You could also use a literal control- that may be more what you really want.